# placing existing matplotlib figures into subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like some advise about how to arrange matplotlib.figure.Figure objects

I make an object of type 'matplotlib.figure.Figure' using the following function (https://nilearn.github.io/modules/generated/nilearn.plotting.plot_surf_roi.html) :

```
from nilearn import plotting

def plot_surf(surface_data, view, fig):
    img = plotting.plot_surf_roi(surface_data['surf_mesh'], 
                        roi_map=surface_data['comp_labels'],
                        hemi=hemi, view=view,
                        cmap='RdBu_r',
                        vmax=np.nanmax(surface_data['comp_labels']), 
                        vmin=np.nanmin(surface_data['comp_labels']),
                        bg_map=surface_data['bg_maps'],
                        darkness=0.6,
                        bg_on_data=True,
                        title='',
                        figure = fig)
    return img
```

I would like to make a few of these and arrange as subplots. This is my unsuccessful attempt so far:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_surf(surface_data, 'lateral', fig)
plot_surf(surface_data, 'medial', fig)
plt.show()
```

Any advice appreciated

Comment: Check this web page: [Creating multiple subplots using plt.subplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to have any advice about how to achieve this specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
def plot_surf(surface_data, view, fig, axes):
    img = plotting.plot_surf_roi(surface_data['surf_mesh'], 
                        roi_map=surface_data['comp_labels'],
                        hemi=hemi, view=view,
                        cmap='RdBu_r',
                        vmax=np.nanmax(surface_data['comp_labels']), 
                        vmin=np.nanmin(surface_data['comp_labels']),
                        bg_map=surface_data['bg_maps'],
                        darkness=0.6,
                        bg_on_data=True,
                        title='',
                        figure = fig,
                        axes=axes)
    return img

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'}) 
plot_surf(surface_data, 'lateral', fig, ax1)
plot_surf(surface_data, 'medial', fig, ax2)
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives the error:
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'view_init'

Comment: Just needs to be changed to: fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})